# Using execute function in sql as value for update - set

Tags: mysql, sql

if we have a created function like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION name () 
RETURNING INT

...

END FUNCTION
```

can I use it in an update station like -

```
UPDATE table SET value = execute function name()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
UPDATE table SET value = name();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it, but without the `execute function`